# Zero locus of $r$ homogeneous polynomials in $\mathbb{P}^{N}$ where $r\leq N$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

On my notes I have the following statement:

Let $F_{1},\dots,F_{r}$ be homogeneous polynomials in $k[x_{0},\dots,x_{N}]$ ($k$ algebraically closed field) with $r\leq N$. Then $X=V(F_{1},\dots,F_{r})\subseteq\mathbb{P}^{N}$ is non empty and every irreducible component of $X$ has dimensione at least $N-r$.

The proof for the non-emptyness is done by induction on $r$. But don't we need some extra hypothesis to guarantee that the locus is non-empty? I.E: let's start with $r=1$. Then $X=V(F_{1})$ is a hypersurface if the polynomial is not constant (and homogeneous). How do we know that from the hypothesis?

Thanks for helping !

Comment: I'm confused about your question - are you asking about why we know that $V(F_1)$ has a point? If so, for nonconstant $F_1$, this is just the projective nullstellensatz. If you're asking about more/different things, please clarify.

Comment: Thank you for answering. My question is: since in the hypothesis of the statement, it is not assumed that the polynomials $F_{i}$ are non-constant, is the proposition still true?

Comment: It's probably a minor oversight on the part of the lecturer. If $F_1=1$, for instance, then $X$ is empty. Probably the cleanest to state the proposition is to assume all $F_i$ are nonconstant and deal with the presence of constant polynomials as a side case. Any nonzero nonconstant polynomial makes $X$ empty, and any $F_i$ that's zero can be ignored.

Comment: Thank you very much, now it's clear :)